# How to sum numbers in nested arrays in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I got this array:

```
array = [["R.M", 20], ["R.U-CS", 3], ["R.M-TIC", 3], ["R.J.CONF", 20]]
```

I want to `sum` the numeric values, so I have converted this into a single array by using `flatten`:

```
array = array.flatten
#=> ["R.M", 20, "R.U-CS", 3, "R.M-TIC", 3, "R.J.CONF", 20]
```

then:

```
a = []
array.each do |r|
  a << r if r.class == Fixnum
end
a
```

This works, but I am searching for a simpler solution, maybe converting the array into an "only `numeric`" array first:

```
[20, 3, 3, 20]
```

Comment: You can, for example. combine `select` with `is_a?`

Comment: Thanks :), it works for me

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Comment: "I want to remove the string values from this array to get only the numeric values" – Great! The way you do it is by writing some code that does what you want. If you have trouble with your code, you research the problems, debug your code, write test cases, single-step the execution, trace the flow of control and data on a piece of paper, sleep on it, try again on the next day, and then *and only then* if you *still* can't figure it out, you ask a focused, complete, narrow question on [so].

Comment: I will keep this in mind @JörgWMittag, please remove DV

Comment: @VishwasNahar if you assume that you have received a downvote because your question is lacking information, you should edit it and add the missing parts, i.e. show what you have tried, describe the problems you are facing etc. Even if your problem is already solved – this site is meant to help future visitors, too.

Comment: Is this array derived from a hash?

Comment: Okay @Stefan i update my problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not that obvious, but you can pass a class or module to [`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) to select its instances:

```
array.grep(Integer)
#=> [20, 3, 3, 20]
```

or

```
array.grep(Numeric)
#=> [20, 3, 3, 20]
```

or to [`grep_v`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) in order to *exclude* its instances:

```
array.grep_v(String)
#=> [20, 3, 3, 20]
```

This works because `grep` uses `===` for pattern matching. If you pass a class, it invokes [`Module#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) (each class is a module) which returns `true` if the object is an instance of the receiver:

```
Integer === 20
#=> true

Integer === 'foo'
#=> false
```

---

**However**, your actual problem can be solved much easier. Given this array:

```
array = [["R.M", 20], ["R.U-CS", 3], ["R.M-TIC", 3], ["R.J.CONF", 20]]
```

And assuming that the second value is always a number, you can use [`sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-sum) with a block:

```
array.sum { |string, number| number }
#=> 46
```

or to sum each sub-array's [`last`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-last) value: (which is the same in this case)

```
array.sum(&:last)
#=> 46
```

Comment: This! I permanently forget about this wonderful `grep`. **This is the correct answer and it should be marked.**

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes and no. To make this cat happy one should use the most readable way to accomplish the task. This is it.

Comment: I found this one helpful  `array.sum(&:last)`. Thanks @stefan

Answer (score 3):

One might use class’ case-equality [`Module#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) to determine a class of elements and to reject strings:

```
array =  ["R.M", 20, "R.U-CS", 3, "R.M-TIC", 3, "R.J.CONF", 20]
array.reject &String.method(:===)
#⇒ [
#   [0] 20,
#   [1] 3,
#   [2] 3,
#   [3] 20
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.delete_if { |x| x.kind_of(String) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.map { |item| item if item.is_a? Integer }.compact

# [20, 3, 3, 20]
```

More compact:

```
array.select { |item| item.is_a? Integer }
```

Or even shorter:

```
array.select &Integer.method(:===)
```

Comment: You misuse `map` here.

Comment: `map.compact` is one loop more than `select`.

Comment: The `item if` part in your `select` block is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below code

```
array.reject { |c| c.class.name.eql?('String') }
```

With `is_a?`

```
array.reject { |c| c.is_a?(String) }
```

Comment: Why class name check and not `is_a?`?

Comment: We can use both @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Thanks @Bharatsoni

Comment: Why can't we use the class.name any reason for that ?

Comment: @VishwasNahar If I solved your problem please accept the answer.

Comment: With `class.name` you would not detect derived classes. (Which may be correct, it depends on the requirement).

Comment: sure @Bharatsoni

Comment: @Bharatsoni counter question: why should we use `class.name`, any reason for that? Given that we have `is_a?`.

Comment: The accepted answer should be the `grep`/`grep_v` one. `c.class.name.eql?('String')` is completely un-rubyish.

Answer (score 0):

use `select` to select only integers from the array

```
array =  ["R.M", 20, "R.U-CS", 3, "R.M-TIC", 3, "R.J.CONF", 20]
array.select { |tmp| tmp.is_a?(Integer) }
#=> [20, 3, 3, 20]
```

use `select!` if you want to permanently change the content of your variable `array` with the integer-only content

Comment: Ruby isn't Python or Java. No need to write `select()` when `select` is enough.

Comment: @EricDuminil point noted .. some other methods from `Enumerable` like `inject({})` takes in args .. so parentheses just slips in while using enumerable methods

Comment: Yes. Note that `inject` does not always need an argument.

Answer (score 0):

*If* your arrays are formatted like your example then this will work:

```
array.select.with_index { |_,i| i.odd? } #=> [20, 3, 3, 20]
```